# where clause in mysql pivot qyery

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

**Table**

```
+-----------------+------------+--------------+
| submit_time     | field_name | field_value  |
+-----------------+------------+--------------+
| 1410098760.2225 |  cap       |  40128       |
| 1410098760.2225 |  provincia |  Bologna     |
| 1410098760.2225 |  localita  |  Bologna     |
| 1410098760.2225 |  indirizzo |  Via roma    |
| 1410098760.2225 |  zodiaco   |  Pesci       |
| 1410098760.2225 |  anno      |  1964        |
| 1410098760.2225 |  mese      |  03          |
| 1410098760.2225 |  giorno    |  10          |
| 1410098760.2225 |  card      |  12          |
+-----------------+------------+--------------+
```

this is my query,

```
SELECT 
  submit_time,
  Max(if(field_name = 'nome', field_value, NULL)) AS nome,
  Max(if(field_name = 'giorno', field_value, NULL)) AS giorno,
  Max(if(field_name = 'mese', field_value, NULL)) AS mese,
  Max(if(field_name = 'anno', field_value, NULL)) AS anno,
  Max(if(field_name = 'card', field_value, NULL)) AS card,
  Max(if(field_name = 'localita', field_value, NULL)) AS localita,
  Max(if(field_name = 'indirizzo', field_value, NULL)) AS indirizzo,
  Max(if(field_name = 'email', field_value, NULL)) AS email,
  Max(if(field_name = 'tel', field_value, NULL)) AS tel,
  Max(if(field_name = 'cellulare', field_value, NULL)) AS cellulare    
FROM zhter9mu3cf7dbplugin_submits    
GROUP BY submit_time
```

This works perfect but if I use a where clause

```
where field_name = 'card' and field_value = 12
```

all field are empty. Any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: Please provide some sample table data

Comment: What will return with `select count(*) from zhter9mu3cf7dbplugin_submits where field_name = 'card' and field_value = 12`?

Comment: @JaugarChang
it return one line, all fields empty exept field 'card'

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you use the `WHERE` clause to filter your `field_name = 'card' and field_value = 12` you return a single row.

You are basically removing the rows with other `field_names`.  You can see this by doing the following with your sample data:

```
select *
from submits
where field_name = 'card' 
  and field_value = 12
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc4d5/3). This only returns the rows with the `field_name` and `field_value` you requested.  There is nothing else to put in the other columns so you return null.

If you want to return the `submit_time` that has the same `field_name` and `field_value` you are filtering, then you could use:

```
SELECT 
  submit_time,
  Max(if(field_name = 'nome', field_value, NULL)) AS nome,
  Max(if(field_name = 'giorno', field_value, NULL)) AS giorno,
  Max(if(field_name = 'mese', field_value, NULL)) AS mese,
  Max(if(field_name = 'anno', field_value, NULL)) AS anno,
  Max(if(field_name = 'card', field_value, NULL)) AS card,
  Max(if(field_name = 'localita', field_value, NULL)) AS localita,
  Max(if(field_name = 'indirizzo', field_value, NULL)) AS indirizzo,
  Max(if(field_name = 'email', field_value, NULL)) AS email,
  Max(if(field_name = 'tel', field_value, NULL)) AS tel,
  Max(if(field_name = 'cellulare', field_value, NULL)) AS cellulare    
FROM submits s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM submits f
              WHERE f.field_name = 'card' 
                AND f.field_value = '12'
                AND f.submit_time = s.submit_time)
GROUP BY submit_time;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc4d5/9)

Comment: @andymo There is no problem to solve. You can't return the other values if you filter for a single value.  Maybe if you explain exactly what you are trying to do then a solution could be found.  Edit your question with some sample data and the final desired result.

Comment: basicly it's a pivot table my problem is filtering the row extracted by a card with id = 12
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc4d5/7

Comment: @andymo I get it's a pivot that you are trying to do, but your requirements aren't clear.  Sounds like maybe you want to do something like this -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc4d5/9

Comment: Sorry to jump in, I think where clause inside where exists should be s.field_name = 'card' and s.field_value = '12'